# Create a virtualenv get ERROR

Tags: python, virtualenv

I create a virtualenv with "virtualenv testENV"
but it show me error like this picture

[image]

it said that i installed Python for "Only the user", but i didn't.
so if there is someone can tell me how to fix that.

```
[WIN10x64, python3.6x64]
```

Comment: Have you tried installing python on a path that only contains ascii characters? Something like E:\python3.6\

Comment: thanks a lot!!!! I didn't think about my python path. thanks for solving this problem.